# How to query for multiple wildcard operators in a sigle query?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the below code everything is fine but my values are not matching to what they should be, I want to understand if I am using the wildcard operator correctly, that is I want to pull multiple values from the column post_evar10 using wildcard. I get correct results when I use one wildcard operator at a time.

```
where (post_evar10 like 'states:%' or 
       post_evar10 like 'www:' or 
       post_evar10 like 'local:%' or 
       post_evar10 like 'learn:%')

create table temp.MS_Adobe_Discover1

Select 
  concat(month(date_time),'/',day(date_time),'/', year(date_time)) as Date, 
  post_evar10, 
  count(page_event) as Pageviews, 
  count(distinct concat(post_visid_high, post_visid_low)) as UniqueVisitors 
from adobe_hits
where (post_evar10 like 'states:%' or 
       post_evar10 like 'www:' or 
       post_evar10 like 'local:%' or 
       post_evar10 like 'learn:%')
  and page_event like '0'
  and exclude_hit like '0'
  and hit_source not in (5,7,8,9)
group by Date, post_evar10;
```

Sample Result:
Please see the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qk2d.png)

Comment: Is the problem that you're not seeing the `www:` values? This term: `post_evar10 like 'www:'` appears to be missing a `%`.

Comment: Here: `post_evar10 like 'www:'` did you miss a wildcard? If not you can write it like `post_evar10 = 'www:'`

Comment: can you give more detail?  What is an example of a record you are not getting?

Comment: the problem is not www: I want to pull it without the wildcard, I want to understand if my way of using multiple wildcard in that line with or is the right way to do it? I am just trying to pull sum of values (pageviews and unique visitors) grouped by post_evar10

Comment: added an image of the result.

Comment: you can also use left

Comment: I have added an image of the final output.

Comment: @NewCode, the right way is defined by you. Does query generate your desired results in the time you need it to? Then it is right. Without input data, image of (truncated?) output is not too helpful.

Comment: @NewCode the image of the results included only have results where `post_evar10` begins with "states:". Are you sure there are supposed to be results that start with different values? Try removing the other conditions in the `where` clause (e.g. `or page_event like '0' `) and verify that there are results for just the the filter expressions `post_evar10 like ... or post_evar10 like ...`. After verifying that, then add the other filter expressions back into `where` class one at a time and see if results are getting filtered out that were expecting to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use left which might be faster on some systems and some data sets --- like this:

```
 where (left(post_evar10,7) = 'states:' or 
        post_evar10 = 'www:' or
        post_evar10,6) = 'local:' or 
        post_evar10,6) = 'learn:')
```

if you don't care about the `:` in `states:` this would def. be faster

```
 where (left(post_evar10,6) in ('states','local:','learn:') or 
        post_evar10 = 'www:' )
```